# faster combinatorial function

Tags: math, haskell, combinatorics

Given a list

```
ms = [2,1,1,1]
```

of multiplicities, a stock of prime numbers corresponding to ms (here, the stock could be : 2,2,3,5,7) and a list, of length lc,

```
cs = [3,1,1]
```

of capacities, we consider any list xs of length lc such that xs !! i = product of (cs !! i) numbers from the stock, 0 <= i < lc, the stock being empty at the end of the construction of xs (so

```
sum ms == sum cs
```

should hold).

Here are, for instance, the 13 possibilities for xs with the chosen stock:

```
  [12,5,7], [12,7,5], [20,3,7], [20,7,3]
, [28,3,5], [28,5,3], [30,3,7], [30,7,3]
, [42,2,5], [42,5,2], [70,2,3], [70,3,2], [105,2,2].
```

The programming problem is to write a fast function

```
nbOfLists :: (Integral a,Integral b) => [a] -> [a] -> b
```

counting the number of distinct such lists (here nbOfLists ms cs == 13).

Here is a solution in Haskell

```
nbOfLists [u] _     = 1
nbOfLists (u:us) vs = 
    let clean = map (filter (/=0))
        corpus = filter (all (>=0)) $ map (zipWith (-) vs) $ base u (length vs)
        base k 1 = [[k]]
        base k l = concat [map (i :) $ base (k-i) (l-1) | i <- [0..k]]
    in sum $ map (nbOfLists us) $ clean corpus
```

that performs nbOfLists [2..6] [2..6] == 604137 in 10s. Can you do better ?

By the way, can you proove that nbOfLists ms cs == nbOfLists cs ms ? That is, for instance, from the 2,2,2,3,5 stock, xs is among the 13 lists :

```
  [4,2,3,5], [4,2,5,3],  [4,3,2,5],  [4,3,5,2]
, [4,5,2,3], [4,5,3,2],  [6,2,2,5],  [6,2,5,2]
, [6,5,2,2], [10,2,2,3], [10,2,3,2], [10,3,2,2], [15,2,2,2]
```

(I have no clue here) ?

Comment: This feels an awful lot of a competition or homework.

Comment: I feel like there must be some relationship to the [Multinomial Coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html) here, but I have yet to tease it out.

Comment: Still trying to come up with an algorithm, but I posted a [related question over at MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53132/combinatorial-questions-about-multisets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the problem is about. We are given a set of items of several types expressed by the list `ms`. For example, `ms=[2,1,1,1]` means that we have 2 items of the first type, 1 item of the second type and so on. We want to count the number of ways to put all items into `lc` boxes so that the `i`-th box contained `cs!!i` items.

I will answer your question about symmetry: **can you prove that `nbOfLists ms cs == nbOfLists cs ms`?** Let's encode each distribution of the items by a bipartite graph. The nodes of one part will correspond to types of items, the nodes of the other part to boxes, and each time we put an item of type `i` to the `j`-th box we'll draw the edge `i-j`. The conditions of the problem mean the the degrees of nodes in the first part must be equal to `ms` and the degrees of the nodes of the second part to `cs`. So `nbOfLists` is the number of bipartite graphs with degree vectors `ms` and `cs`. But this definition is symmetrical with respect to `ms` and `cs`! So the `nbOfLists` must be symmetrical as well.

I don't know whether there exists a non-bruteforce algorithm for this problem but I hope I at least clarified it a bit.

Comment: very clear indeed, I will accept your answer if no other algorithm is submitted. Thanks for the proof anyway!